# scayt button doesn't show up nor scayt functions work

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, scayt

I'm trying to fix my ckeditor - scayt issue since days and found nothing on internet that works.  I'm begging your help.

Here is my config.js file --- toolbar definition:

```
    config.toolbar_Reduite = [
{ name: 'Fichiers', items: ['Source']},
{ name: 'FaireDefaire', items: ['Undo','Redo','-', 'Scayt', 'SpellChecker']},
{ name: 'Polices', items: 
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Subscript','Superscript','RemoveFormat']},
{ name: 'CopieColle', items: 
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord']},
{ name: 'ListeDec', items: ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-', 
    'Outdent','Indent','Blockquote']},
{ name: 'Justifie', items:    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter', 
'JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','Link','Unlink']},
{ name: 'Tableaux', items: ['Table','HorizontalRule','TextColor','BGColor']}
];
```

And there my specific textareat ckeditor replacement

```
        var CKcontenu = CKEDITOR.replace( 'contenu', { toolbar : 'Reduite',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'outils/ckeditor_ChoisirImage.php',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'outils/ckeditor_RecevoirImage.php',
    extraPlugins : 'linkayt,scayt',

        disableNativeSpellChecker : false,
        scayt_srcUrl : 'http://spellcheck_host/spellcheck/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/ckscayt.js',
        scayt_maxSuggestions : 4,
        scayt_sLang : 'fr_CA',
        scayt_userDictionaryName : '../nanospell/server/dictionaries',
        scayt_customDictionaryIds : 'fr.dic,en.dic,es.dic',
        scayt_moreSuggestions : 'off',
        scayt_contextCommands : 'add|ignoreall',
        scayt_uiTabs : '1,0,1',
        scayt_contextMenuItemsOrder :'moresuggest|control|suggest',
        scayt_minWordLength : 4,
        scayt_elementsToIgnore : 'del,pre',
        scayt_disableOptionsStorage : ['lang', 'ignore-all-caps-words', 'ignore-words-with-mixed-cases'],
        scayt_ignoreWordsWithNumbers : true,
        scayt_ignoreDomainNames : true,
        scayt_ignoreWordsWithMixedCases : true,
        scayt_ignoreAllCapsWords : true,
        scayt_inlineModeImmediateMarkup : true,
        scayt_multiLanguageMode : true,
        scayt_autoStartup : true,
        language_list : ['en:English', 'fr:Français', 'es:Espaañol', ],
        scayt_multiLanguageStyles : {'en': 'background-image: none; color: blue', 'es': 'background-image: none; color: orange', 'fr': 'background-image: none; color: red' },


} );
```

But still, the Scayt button doesn't show up.
Also, the SpellChecker button doesn't offer the scayt options as you can see in the attached image:

[image]

How can I fix it ?

ckeditor version: 4.5.11
scayt version: not sure, but dowloaded last week, README says: « This plugin brings Spell Check As You Type (SCAYT) into up to CKEditor 4+. »

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. What did you mean in the next option: `scayt_userDictionaryName : '../nanospell/server/dictionaries'`. Nanospell? In next option you should pass right url address: `scayt_srcUrl : 'http://spellcheck_host/spellcheck/lf/scayt3/ckscayt/ckscayt.js'`. Spellcheck_host - only for example.

Answer (score 0):

When I take all configurations off, it works well.

So, how can I configure and regulate the scayt:  mostly default language, languages list ?

This (below) doesn't work:

```
        scayt_sLang : 'fr_CA',
    language_list : ['en:English', 'fr:Français', 'es:Espaañol', ],
    scayt_multiLanguageStyles : {'en': 'background-image: none; color: blue', 'es': 'background-image: none; color: orange', 'fr': 'background-image: none; color: red' },
```

Thanks

Comment: You can find information about SCAYT configuration following next links: [https://wiki.webspellchecker.net/doku.php?id=scayt_parameters_ckeditor4](https://wiki.webspellchecker.net/doku.php?id=scayt_parameters_ckeditor4), [https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_scayt.html](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_scayt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can start from simple demo with right CKEditor and SCAYT configuration and add all additional options step by step if you need.

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [{
    name: 'editing',
    items: ['Scayt', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline']
}];

CKEDITOR.replace('container', {
    scayt_autoStartup: true,
    grayt_autoStartup: true
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jalners/j4ytgb2v/